# how to duplicate a folder and its subfolders in the same directory using cmd in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, user-folders

I want to duplicate one folder with its subfolders in the same directory using the command prompt. But I am stuck as I cannot find a way to rename the duplicate folder.

I have tried

```
xcopy "TEMPLATE FOLDER" [destination]
```

I have also tried

```
copy "TEMPLATE FOLDER" [destination]
```

In my case the [destination] is the same folder where the "TEMPLATE FOLDER" is. I would like have the following directory

```
D:\dir1\dir2\dir3
11/28/2018  08:50 AM    <DIR>          .
11/28/2018  08:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/23/2018  08:31 AM    <DIR>          TEMPLATE FOLDER
```

As such:

```
D:\dir1\dir2\dir3
11/28/2018  08:50 AM    <DIR>          .
11/28/2018  08:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/23/2018  08:31 AM    <DIR>          TEMPLATE FOLDER
11/23/2018  08:31 AM    <DIR>          TEMPLATE FOLDER2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
xcopy /i "TEMPLATE FOLDER" "TEMPLATE FOLDER2"
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried as you said but it did not work

Comment: @Epilotus So what was the error message? What was the result of running the command?

Comment: @Epilotus You need `xcopy /i "TEMPLATE FOLDER"\* "TEMPLATE FOLDER2"` if the source folder contains subdirectories.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, thanks for the help. I tried the sintax and it shows `0 file(s) copied`. Indeed the directory contains subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

I researched further and found a way to duplicate my folder. Here is how I did it:

`xcopy /E "TEMPLATE FOLDER" "TEMPLATE FOLDER2"`

So there is no need to add a destination as it will automatically use the directory that I am in. And combined with the `/E` flag, it copies the empty subfolders (this seems to be a requirement).

Thanks for the help @DavidPostill and @Scott